# AMP: Accelerated Mobile Pages in an already developed site

Tags: performance, mobile, amp-html

I have an umbraco based CMS site and I've been advised to use AMP for fast mobile performance. I have read the demo page from this [gitHub link](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/examples/metadata-examples/article-json-ld.amp.html).

But I am not understanding how to set it in an already developed site. Do I need to change all tags according to AMP?

Answer (score 0):

better not to mess with existing instead you build new AMP version of your site

Answer (score 0):

(After doing a quick Google)

I don't think there's a an AMP-plugin for Umbraco yet, but that will probably be the way to go. I've been using the AMP-plugin for WordPress for a little while now and it made all posts on my site AMP-compatible without me having to do anything :)

Perhaps check with the Umbraco community whether there's an ETA on such a plugin for their platform?

Answer (score 0):

You can have seperate AMP pages and google will handle the rest. I think that is the safest way to approach it, without having a plugin like they have for wordpress.

You can still enable the users to use the CMS functionality by creating custom data types for e.g. amp-img instead of img. The content editors will just have to be briefed on the basics of AMP.

References:

https://carolelogan.net/blog/amp-implementation-in-umbraco/

https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/discovery